# Vue JS Component template rendering issue when testing

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having issues at the moment with testing a vue component, the code below actually works but testing does not play ball. I have done some searching and I am aware there is an issue where Vue 2.0 only uses runtime-only build when importing vue and that I need to use vue/esm or use the render function. The problem I have with that is that i am not using webpack or any build system (using tsconfig) to create an alias.

I have tried just using template:'' and it still errors out. When i use the render/createElement function I can't seem to add in my own html file/template as it seems to only want to create a new element rather than inject a template.

ERROR: '[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

COMPONENT:

```
import {
    debounce
}
from 'npmPackage/debounce';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import './navigation-bar.styles.less';
import {
    menuItemList,
    secondaryButton
}
from './types';

 @ Component({
    props: ['panels', 'secondaryButton'],
    // render: (createElement) => { return createElement('div', require('./navigation-bar.html')); }
    template: require('./navigation-bar.html')
})

export class NavigationBar extends Vue {
    public menuActive: boolean = false;
    public menuClass: string = '';
    public panels: menuItemList;
    public secondaryButton: secondaryButton;

    private animateMenu: () => void = debounce(this.toggleMenuClass, 300, true);

    public toggleMenu(): void {
        this.animateMenu();
    }

    private toggleMenuClass(): void {
        this.menuActive = !this.menuActive;
        this.menuClass = this.menuActive ? 'show' : 'hide';
    }
}

Vue.component('navigation-bar', NavigationBar);
```

UNIT TEST:

```
import {
    expect
}
from 'chai';
import {
    spy,
    stub
}
from 'sinon';
import Vue from 'vue';
import {
    NavigationBar
}
from '../src/navigation-bar.component'
import {
    IMenuItem
}
from "../src/types";

describe('Navigation bar component', () => {
    let panels: Array < IMenuItem > ;
    let navigationBar: NavigationBar;

    beforeEach(() => {
        panels = [{
                label: 'my-account',
                action: function () {}
            }, {
                label: 'home',
                action: stub
            }
        ];
        navigationBar = new NavigationBar();
        navigationBar.$mount();
    });

    describe('Checks that only one action is being called per panel', () => {
        it('checks actions are called', () => {
            console.log(navigationBar.$el);
            navigationBar.panels = panels;
            const menuItem = navigationBar.$el.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
            menuItem.length.should.equal(panels.length);

            const menuItem1 = menuItem[0];
            menuItem1.should.be.instanceOf(HTMLElement);
            const html = menuItem1 as HTMLElement;
            html.click();
            panels[0].action.should.have.been.calledOnce;
            panels[1].action.should.not.have.been.called;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of the CDN version of Vue and import that instead of the npm Vue.

Or alternatively you could `import Vue from vue/dist/vue.js`

[image]

Comment: I have also tried this to no avail. It does not find the /dist from the component and adding the CDN script to the html does not give me access to use it in the typescript vue component.

Comment: Yeah you should probably ditch typescript because then you are cross-compiling, and you probably end up losing some functionality somewhere. I was wondering why your syntax looked so different.

Comment: Or at least use Webpack with TypeScript.

Comment: In my current situation I can't do that. i'm building this as an npm package to put into a very large codebase. Trying to keep it simple also. I have been trying to get the html to compile when unit testing for awhile now and every method so far has failed. Thanks for the help though, you would assume it would work but I must have something seriously wrong somewhere

Comment: It could be something with the class component that you are pulling in. Did you try pulling in your class component before vue? Alternatively, Vue already has a component syntax that you are using at the very bottom. try plugging the template code in there and see if it works.

Comment: replace this `Vue.component('navigation-bar', NavigationBar);` with this `Vue.component('navigation-bar', { template:' <div>whatever</div>'});`